# QNAP QTS HD-Station (TS-251) setting Full Range RGB 0-255 with Xrandr

Tags: rgb, nas, hdmi, xrandr, qnap

How do I configure my QNAP HD-Station to Full Range RGB 0-255?

Running QTS 4.1.4

Comment: This is off-topic for stackoverflow, as it's not a programming issue. I've flagged it for migration to [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Ooops, sorry. Just wanted to share my knowledge somewhere.

Comment: It definitely seems like a useful and well-researched question + answer, just a bit off-topic :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy, if you know how to do it. First of all, connect to your NAS through SSH. Execute these 2 commands:

```
chroot /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/HD_Station /bin/bash
xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

Or, if you want to make the change permanent (i.e. setting Full RGB when your NAS reboots), you need to edit this file

```
vi /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/HD_Station/etc/HD_Station/init.d/xrandr-hotplug.sh
```

add line:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

and reboot your NAS.